# How to pass multiple pytest command line options in the run configuration

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, python-logging

**Question**

How to pass multiple pytest command line options in PyCharm?

**Problem**

Setting the pytest logging options `--log-level=DEBUG --log-cli=True --log-cli-level=DEBUG` fails with the error with the PyCharm Run Configuration.

[image]

```
Launching pytest with arguments --log-level=DEBUG --log-cli=True --log-cli-level=DEBUG ****/test_040_objective_sigmoid.py in ****

ERROR: usage: _jb_pytest_runner.py [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
_jb_pytest_runner.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --log-cli=True
  inifile: None
  rootdir: ****
```

With single argument, it runs without an error.

[image]

```
Launching pytest with arguments --log-level=DEBUG ****test_040_objective_sigmoid.py in ****

============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- ****/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: ****
plugins: pytest_check-1.0.1
collecting ... collected 5 items
```

When running the pytest from command line, the pytest logging options work.

```
$ pytest --log-level=DEBUG --log-cli=True --log-cli-level=DEBUG --verbose --cache-clear -x ${DIR}
=============================================================================================== 
test session starts
===============================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
...
```

**pytest setup in PyCharm**

[image]

**References**

- [Run/Debug Configuration: pytest](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-py-test.html)
- [Pytest Logging](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/logging.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pytest uses a mixture of single `-` and double `--` hyphens preceding the command line options, some are used without an hyphen. In your example only `--log-level` uses a double hyphen.

The remaining two options `log_cli` and `log_cli_level` are written without any leading hyphen and have an underscore in the middle of the name. Those two are also ["Configuration Options"](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#configuration-options) and may need to be prefixed with `-o`.

A complete reference can be found in [Command-line Flags](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#command-line-flags).

So instead of:

`--log-level=DEBUG --log-cli=True --log-cli-level=DEBUG`

try:

`--log-level=DEBUG -o log_cli=True -o log_cli_level=DEBUG`

[image: screenshot of run configurations]

```
C:\path_to your_project\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pycharm\_jb_pytest_runner.py" --path C:/path_to your_project/tests/basic_test.py -- --log-level=DEBUG -v -o log_cli=True -o log_cli_level=DEBUG
Testing started at 3:05 AM ...
Launching pytest with arguments --log-level=DEBUG -v -o log_cli=True -o log_cli_level=DEBUG C:/path_to your_project/tests/basic_test.py in C:\path_to your_project

============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.0, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- C:\path_to your_project\venv\Scripts\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: C:\path_to your_project, configfile: pytest.ini
collecting ... collected 1 item

tests/basic_test.py::test_validate_args PASSED                      [100%]

============================== 1 passed in 0.02s ==============================

Process finished with exit code 0
```